# nginx/angular/node.js root URL with prerender.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nginx, url-routing

We have an angular SPA using node, nginx, and [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/). Our home page is set as a unique url (i.e. www.foo.com/bar) and in our routing, this home page captures the default redirect of all root-relative urls not specifically routed otherwise.

**Our problem is this:** the root url www.foo.com or www.foo.com/ comes back with a blank page scrape for google and Facebook. Our index is an ng-include basic template that all pages are inserted inside of, so it makes sense that our root url comes back without any real html body content. Main html in index:

```
<div class="st-content">
  <div ng-view="" class="main-content" id="mainView"></div>
  <div ng-include="'/views/footer.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Additionally, we have tried other solutions without positive results:

- base tag in the index head linking to '/', which did not break anything… it also did not resolve it
- 307 redirect, no results
- nginx configs look good

**Note:** in writing this question it occurred to me to change the home routing to ‘/':

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/views/foo-bar.html',
    title: ‘Foo Bar',
    pageDescription: ‘Lorem Ipsum Foo Bar'
})
    .
    .
    .
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

If changed to this will the home scrape still show as blank? Isn’t this basically the same js redirect problem, but with less characters?

Comment: I didn't get if nginx is configured to respond with your `index.html` for all requests on `foo.com` or `www.foo.com`. Is it? Are you using HTML5 mode by the way?

Comment: Can you send me the actual URL in question? I'd be happy to test it and see what's going on there to make sure everything is set up correctly. todd@prerender.io

Comment: @DanM. Nginx is configured for 301 redirect for all requests to foo.com. www.foo.com is then proxied to node.js. Strace-ing nginx and node show that nginx is appropriately proxying to the node server, at which point we see the node requests and responses. Also, we are using HTML5 mode.

Comment: That sounds about right. When you say 'blank' page scrape, do you mean just an empty <body> or your Angular index without the dynamic content?

Comment: Also, do you have the `meta fragment` in your index? For prerender to work you need that and you also need to specify it in the URL when you crawl as Google (I assume you use webmaster tools for it) => foo.bar/path?_escaped_fragment_=

Comment: @DanM. thanks for the comments. By 'blank' I mean our Angular index without the dynamic content. We are using the meta fragment in our index... and as far as prerender, Todd from Prerender has been emailing us about set up questions. I'll share the feedback once we resolve this

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `window.prerenderReady` variable. Thus, put this in your route controller:

```
window.prerenderReady = false;
```

... and this in your controller's success callback function:

`window.prerenderReady = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem not long ago.

Do you have a code fragment that prerender.io would not be able to run?

In my case, I was using platform.js (https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/), and was doing a test in my appComponent.ts about "platform.name". This was not existing in Prerender.io, and I was getting a blank page.